# Selector Panel, Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
    $('#select-page').bind('change', function(){
        alert('hi!');
    });

        <select id="select-page">
          <option value="hi">Page 1</option>
          <option value="hi2">Page 2</option>
           <!-- the amount of options in here varies all the time -->
        </select>
```

Howdy,

I am trying to make a tabs switching-panel sort of feature except instead of tabs, I want to use a select drop down to switch between panels (divs).

How can I accomplish this? (I am using the jQuery library).

Have a good day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this.

#### Html

```
<select id="select-page">
    <option value="#hi">Page 1</option> <!--Set the options id of the div/panel to be displayed-->
    <option value="#hi2">Page 2</option>
    <option value="#hi3">Page 3</option>
    <option value="#hi4">Page 4</option>
    <!-- the amount of options in here varies -->
</select>
<div class="content" id="hi">Content1</div>
<div class="content" id="hi2">Content2</div>
<div class="content" id="hi3">Content3</div>
<div class="content" id="hi4">Content4</div>
```

#### JS

```
$(function(){
    $('.content').eq(0).show(); //show the first item as default
    $('#select-page').bind('change', function () {
        $('.content').slideUp(); //slide up everything.You can also use .hide() insetad of slideUp().
        $(this.value).slideDown(); //slide down the one respective to this option. You can also use .show() instead of slideDown()
    });
});
```

You can utilize chaining and filter out to just one statement for this kind of simple layout.

```
$('#select-page').bind('change', function () {
    $('.content').slideUp().filter(this.value).slideDown();
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/B7LYA/)

Some references

[slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/), [slideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/),
[show](http://api.jquery.com/show/),
[hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/),
[filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)